# Minimization of a difference between model and observation by optimizing a single parameter

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I admit I am not sure whether this question is better suited here on StackOverflow or elsewhere, because I am not sure if it is just programming or the whole concept that I need to understand. If off-topic, I apologise.

In Python, I am creating a rather simple model. It is a function that takes an array `x`, several coefficients `c1`, `c2` etc., and a parameter `P` that I want to optimize. 
I want to minimize the difference between the measured and modelled values by changing the parameter `P` and as an output, I would like the resulting parameter (scalar) and the resulting difference between the model and the measurement (array).

I have been studying the `scipy.optimize.minimize` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) for a while, but I don't seem to get it. In particular, I don't understand:

1. How to define the scalar function that enters the minimization so that only the P gets modified.
2. Which minimization method would be best in this case (I have assumed least-squares, but looking at the documentation there are so many other methods that I don't even know that if another is recommended, I am open to that option, provided an explanation comes with the recommendation).
3. How do I get my desired output (as it seems the optimization result is a python object as a whole, but I only want very specific outputs stated above)

Example:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.random.rand(10)
array2 = np.arange(5.,55,5)

from scipy.optimize import minimize

def model(c1, c2, c3, x, P):
    modelY = x*c1 + c2*x*P + c3 # some random function for which I need to optimize P
    return modelY
```

Now what syntax would I use with `scipy.optimize.minimize` if the function whose minimum I want is `np.abs(measured - modelY)` and the only parameter that I want to change is `P`, which is an argument of the `model` function, and use the measured data as an initial guess? Or should I put them into a single function? But then how would I specify to NOT modify all the other arguments of the function except the one? 
And how do I extract the difference and the resulting `P` from the minimization result?

Comment: I think the question is on-topic as it is definitiely about programming (except *2.* - which method to use depends on the problem at hand and is probably not for programmers to answer). However, I'm sure the information you need is scattered around on this site and the documentation. I lack the time to go into more detail at the moment, but for starters have a look at [`curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) which may be easier to use in some cases.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! However, I still don't see how to only modify one scalar in the `curve_fit` and how to return the resulting scalar as an output.

Comment: Probably all of this is mentioned in the docs (some questions of yours are trivial). Without some more complete code it's also hard to show you code as so much is undefined. And the internals of model might also be important for the optimization itself!

Comment: Do you know a plausible range for `P`? If it is a scalar, a simple approach that removes the necessity for selecting a particular minimisation routine is simply making a grid of values for `P` and then evaluating the cost function at each of those values. You can then plot the cost as a function of `P`, and use the results to find the minimum value.

Comment: @AngusWilliams I'm not sure I follow what you mean. Do you mean make an array of all possible values of P and iterate over it? This doesn't seem plausible. I mean, the range is within ~ 0.1 and 10 and I probably don't need a precision greater than two or three decimal points, but even so it doesn't seem very efficient. But I mark your words, if I am desperate, I may end up going that way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question, imho, suffered a lot from the description and parameter-names, but i think i'm getting now what you want to achieve.

I simplified it a bit and present some code with two approaches, the *good one* and the *bad one*. The good one: optimizing one variable is done by using optimizers for a single variable (`minimize_scalar`)! The bad one: using any multivariate-optimizer (`minimize`).

One probably could talk ages about how to use scipy's optimizers, but i won't do that. I will just say: follow the docs! The most important thing (here some excerpt from the minimize-docs):

> The callable is called as method(fun, x0, args, **kwargs, **options) where kwargs corresponds to any other parameters passed to minimize (such as callback, hess, etc.), except the options dict, which has its contents also passed as method parameters pair by pair. Also, if jac has been passed as a bool type, jac and fun are mangled so that fun returns just the function values and jac is converted to a function returning the Jacobian. The method shall return an OptimizeResult object.

**This means:** P is your first parameter in your function you give to scipy's optimizer (in both cases). Everything else, you use either by python's scope rules (variable available for our functions) or by using `args`.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, minimize_scalar
np.random.seed(1)                                            # make this demo deterministic

# Let's define some random-data and use names people can understand!
f_x = np.random.rand(10)
f_y = np.arange(5.,55,5)
c1, c2, c3 = 2, 1.5, 0.321

# Simple loss-function
def loss(P, c1, c2, c3, f_x, f_y):
    modelY = f_x*c1 + f_x*c2*P + c3                                    # prediction (vector)
    return np.linalg.norm(f_y - modelY, 1)                             # l1-loss (scalar)

# GOOD APPROACH: minimize_scalar
result = minimize_scalar(loss, args=(c1, c2, c3, f_x, f_y))
p_at_minimum = result.x  # i'm a scalar!
print('minimize_scalar result: ', p_at_minimum)

# BAD APPROACH: minimize (multivariate) -> need guess / initial value!
result = minimize(loss, np.zeros(1), args=(c1, c2, c3, f_x, f_y))
p_at_minimum = result.x   # i'm a vector!!!
print('minimize result: ', p_at_minimum)
```

Output:

```
minimize_scalar result:  60.1334526945
minimize result:  [ 60.1334535]
```

**Edit:** just recognized, that my var-names are also bad. `f_x` is not some eval of some function and should be called just `x`, but careful: `x` is usually the parameter to optimize!

**Remark:** and always check the results!

E.g.

```
result = minimize_scalar(loss, args=(c1, c2, c3, f_x, f_y))
p_at_minimum = result.x  # i'm a scalar!
print('minimize_scalar result: ', p_at_minimum)
print('success: ', result.success)
# True

result = minimize(loss, np.zeros(1), args=(c1, c2, c3, f_x, f_y))
p_at_minimum = result.x   # i'm a vector!!!
print('minimize result: ', p_at_minimum)
print('success: ', result.success)
# False (precision-loss -> you can check result.message
```

This status is why i recommended minimize_scalar, which uses more assumptions and therefore is more robust (less tuning needed)!

Comment: Oh I see, the initial guess must be an array! hence the error in my previous attempt!

Comment: This looks really good, now I'm looking if it works for my actual data, in case I missed something...

Comment: It can be a list too. But it needs to be some iterable (we are using multivariate optimizers after all) with the right number of values. Scipy is using this dimension-info before setting up the optimization process (observe that no minimize example is using some explicit N; always deduces from x0!).

Comment: So are you sure I don't provide any initial guess for P in the case of scalar minimization? Without an initial guess, I end up with some values of my model shooting to infinity.

Comment: This depends on details not provided. There is no initial guess, just a bracket.

Comment: You are right, it was just an error in the data, now it works!